# Albumart not showing on lock screen?

Tags: lock-screens, 5.1-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-note-4, sprint, album-art

On Android 5.1 on the Samsung Note 4 (sprint), the currently playing track (in any music player, Spotify, whatnot) is no longer shown as the wallpaper on the lockscreen during playback. I really liked this feature and after hours of searching I can't figure out how to get it back. I am willing to root to get it back, but I'm not sure if I can download the bootloader to get back to kitkat.

Is there a way to restore this functionality in lollipop or will I need to find a way to go back to kitkat (or get another phone on it?)

Comment: *Usually* you should have no problem with the cover being displayed on the lockscreen on Android 5.1, but due to the fact that Samsung modifies the Android Framework so heavily, it is possible that you may need to check your settings (per app and in the Settings app as well)